# gson.fromJson Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, json, javafx, gson

json class:

```
package json;

public class RankAPI {
    private String hotStreak;
    private String leagueName;
    private String tier;
    private String freshBlood;
    private String playerOrTeamId;
    private String leaguePoints;
    private String inactive;
    private String rank;
    private String veteran;
    private String queueType;
    private String losses;
    private String playerOrTeamName;
    private String wins;

public String getHotStreak ()
{
    return hotStreak;
}

public void setHotStreak (String hotStreak)
{
    this.hotStreak = hotStreak;
}

public String getLeagueName ()
{
    return leagueName;
}

public void setLeagueName (String leagueName)
{
    this.leagueName = leagueName;
}

public String getTier ()
{
    return tier;
}

public void setTier (String tier)
{
    this.tier = tier;
}

public String getFreshBlood ()
{
    return freshBlood;
}

public void setFreshBlood (String freshBlood)
{
    this.freshBlood = freshBlood;
}

public String getPlayerOrTeamId ()
{
    return playerOrTeamId;
}

public void setPlayerOrTeamId (String playerOrTeamId)
{
    this.playerOrTeamId = playerOrTeamId;
}

public String getLeaguePoints ()
{
    return leaguePoints;
}

public void setLeaguePoints (String leaguePoints)
{
    this.leaguePoints = leaguePoints;
}

public String getInactive ()
{
    return inactive;
}

public void setInactive (String inactive)
{
    this.inactive = inactive;
}

public String getRank ()
{
    return rank;
}

public void setRank (String rank)
{
    this.rank = rank;
}

public String getVeteran ()
{
    return veteran;
}

public void setVeteran (String veteran)
{
    this.veteran = veteran;
}

public String getQueueType ()
{
    return queueType;
}

public void setQueueType (String queueType)
{
    this.queueType = queueType;
}

public String getLosses ()
{
    return losses;
}

public void setLosses (String losses)
{
    this.losses = losses;
}

public String getPlayerOrTeamName ()
{
    return playerOrTeamName;
}

public void setPlayerOrTeamName (String playerOrTeamName)
{
    this.playerOrTeamName = playerOrTeamName;
}

public String getWins ()
{
    return wins;
}

public void setWins (String wins)
{
    this.wins = wins;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [hotStreak = "+hotStreak+", leagueName = "+leagueName+", tier = "+tier+", freshBlood = "+freshBlood+", playerOrTeamId = "+playerOrTeamId+", leaguePoints = "+leaguePoints+", inactive = "+inactive+", rank = "+rank+", veteran = "+veteran+", queueType = "+queueType+", losses = "+losses+", playerOrTeamName = "+playerOrTeamName+", wins = "+wins+"]";
}
}
```

other code:

```
package com.rhidlor.leaguetool;

import json.SummonerAPI;
import json.RankAPI;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {
    public static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public static Gson gson = new Gson();
    public static SummonerAPI summonerAPI;
    public static RankAPI rankAPI;
    public static String summonerJSON = null;
    public static String rankJSON = null;
    public static String username;
    public static String id;
    public String key = "RGAPI-dd11b8d0-3178-4eb1-8dfa-0d5bf6fb1b24";
    //https://na1.api.riotgames.com

@FXML private Label summonerLabel;
@FXML private Label rankLabel;
@FXML private Label winrateLabel;
@FXML private TextField usernameTextField;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    username = usernameTextField.getText();
    try{
        summonerJSON  = getJSON("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + username + "?api_key=" + key);  
    }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    summonerAPI = gson.fromJson(summonerJSON, SummonerAPI.class);
    id = summonerAPI.getId();
    System.out.println("ID: " + id);

    try{
        rankJSON = getJSON("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v3/positions/by-summoner/" + id + "?api_key=" + key);
        System.out.println("This worked");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("This failed");
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }
    rankAPI = gson.fromJson(rankJSON, RankAPI.class);

    setValues(username);
}

public static String getJSON(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}

public void setValues(String username){
    summonerLabel.setText(username + " Level: " + summonerAPI.getSummonerLevel());
    //System.out.println(rankAPI.getWins());
    //rankLabel.setText("Rank: " + rankAPI.getTier() + " " + rankAPI.getRank() + " LP: " + rankAPI.getLeaguePoints());
    //int winrate = (parseInt(rankAPI.getWins()) / (parseInt(rankAPI.getWins()) + parseInt(rankAPI.getLosses()))) * 100;
    //winrateLabel.setText("Winrate: " + winrate + "%");
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

This line causes the error:

```
rankAPI = gson.fromJson(rankJSON, RankAPI.class);
```

Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. The SummonerAPI portion of this code works perfectly and it's json class is nearly identical to the RankAPI json class.

I understand some off the code may not make sense or seem out of place, thats because I was trying to troubleshoot the code but clearly failed.

Comment: It seems like the JSON you receive from the server is a list of objects (array), that means the JSON starts with '[', which indicates an array instead of '{' which indicates an object. So either your server is returning something wrong, or you should expect a list rather than an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the JSON string (`rankJSON`) is an array of JSON documents not a single JSON document.

If you log that JSON you'll see that it starts with `[` e.g.

```
[
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

You are attempting to deserialize it into a single `RankAPI`, you should instead deserialize it into a `List<RankAPI>`, for example;

```
List<RankAPI> r = gson.fromJson(rankJSON, new TypeToken<ArrayList<RankAPI>>(){}.getType());
```

Here's a test case to verify this behaviour:

```
@Test
public void twoWayTransform() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

    List<RankAPI> incomings = Arrays.asList(new RankAPI(), new RankAPI());

    String json = gson.toJson(incomings);

    // use TypeToken to inform Gson about the type of the elements in the generic list
    List<RankAPI> fromJson = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<RankAPI>>(){}.getType());

    assertEquals(2, fromJson.size());
    for (RankAPI incoming : incomings) {
        // this will pass if RankAPI has an equals() method
        assertTrue(fromJson.contains(incoming));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally understand what my issue was now!

Comment: I still haven't got my code working though, I know what my issue is now and I've tried the code you provided but it says: incompatible types: RankAPI cannot be converted to List<RankAPI> .


Any further help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in my answer. I have updated it now: `List<RankAPI> r = gson.fromJson(rankJSON, List.class);`

Comment: Thank you so very much, your help has saved me from ripping any more of my hair out. I don't deserve any more of your time but if you have some to waste I've come across another issue. At this point it probably seems as though I can't think for myself, but when I run the following code I get the error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to json.RankAPI". Code: `System.out.println(rankAPI.get(0).getWins());`

Comment: @DevinHigley I suspect this: "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to json.RankAPI" is a result of attempting to deserialise into a List of a specific type. I have updated the answer to show how to handle that and I have added a test case which should allow you to trial-and-error Gson yourself.